# keep user logged in in xamarin android

Tags: authentication, xamarin.android, sharedpreferences

I've created a login dialog fragment that appears when a user starts the android app. if the user's credentials are correct, then he will be taken to the main activity. now I added a checkbox that corresponds to "keep me logged in". what I want is that when the user checks the checkbox upon the first login, he should be directly taken to the main activity upon the second login without having to go through the login dialog again. here is my code:

code for my login dialog fragment:

```
 private AlertDialog _dialog;
        CheckBox chbx;
        
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.logindlg, container, false);
            Button button = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
            EditText MyeditText1 = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
            EditText MyeditText2 = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText2);
             chbx= view.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkBox1);
            user.Username = MyeditText1.Text;
            user.Password = MyeditText2.Text;
            button.Click += delegate {
                //set the data to the loginpage
                //mOnLoginInforCompleted.inputLoginInforCompleted(MyeditText1.Text.ToString(), MyeditText2.Text.ToString());
                WSlogin.WebService2 ws = new WSlogin.WebService2();
                ws.LoginAsync(MyeditText1.Text, MyeditText2.Text);
                ws.LoginCompleted += Ws_LoginCompleted;

               
                               
                };


            return view;

        }
        private void Ws_LoginCompleted(object sender, WSlogin.LoginCompletedEventArgs e)

        {


            try
            {

                if (e.Result.ValidUser == true)

                {

                    
                    if (chbx.Checked == true)
                    {
                       
                        ISharedPreferencesEditor edit = user.pref.Edit();
                        edit.PutString("Username", user.Username);
                        edit.PutString("Password", user.Password);
                        edit.Apply();
                    }
                    Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "login successful", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    mOnLoginInforCompleted.inputLoginInforCompleted(user.Username, user.Password);
                    Dismiss();

                }

                else


                {
                    //Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "failed", ToastLength.Short).Show();

                    Context context = this.Context;

                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                    alert.SetTitle("login failed");

                    alert.SetMessage("Please, check your credentials!");
                    alert.SetPositiveButton("okay", (senderAlert, args) =>
                    {

                        CloseDialog();
                    });
                    _dialog = alert.Create();

                    _dialog.Show();


                }
            }
            catch (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException exp)
            {
                System.Net.WebException exception = new System.Net.WebException("can't reach server");


                Toast.MakeText(this.Context, "Connection to Server failed", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }

        }
        private void CloseDialog()
        {
            if (_dialog != null)
                _dialog.Dismiss();
        }
        private OnLoginInforCompleted mOnLoginInforCompleted;
        public void setOnLoginInforCompleted(OnLoginInforCompleted onLoginInforCompleted)
        {
            mOnLoginInforCompleted = onLoginInforCompleted;
        }
}
```

code for the activity with MainLauncher=true

```
 [Activity(Label = "FreeLineApp", Theme = "@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
    public class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity,OnLoginInforCompleted
    {
        private AlertDialog _dialog;
        public void inputLoginInforCompleted(string userName, string passWord)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            StartActivity(new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity)));
        }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);
            //  StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
            var current = Connectivity.NetworkAccess;

            if (current == NetworkAccess.Internet)
            {
                string userName = user.pref.GetString("Username", String.Empty);
                string password = user.pref.GetString("Password", String.Empty);
                if (userName == String.Empty || password == String.Empty)
                {
                    MyDialogFragment dialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
                    dialogFragment.setOnLoginInforCompleted(this);

                    dialogFragment.Cancelable = false;
                    var SupportFragmentManager = this.FragmentManager;
                    dialogFragment.Show(SupportFragmentManager, "dialog");
                }

                else
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
                    this.StartActivity(intent);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                

                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                alert.SetTitle("Connection failed");

                alert.SetMessage("Please, check your internet Connection!");
                alert.SetNeutralButton("okay", (senderAlert, args) => {

                    alert.Dispose();
                    MyDialogFragment dialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
                    dialogFragment.setOnLoginInforCompleted(this);

                    dialogFragment.Cancelable = false;
                    var SupportFragmentManager = this.FragmentManager;
                    dialogFragment.Show(SupportFragmentManager, "dialog");

                });
                _dialog = alert.Create();

                _dialog.Show();
            }
            // Create your application here
        }

       
    }
}
```

where pref is a global variable in class user

```
 public static ISharedPreferences pref = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("UserInfo", FileCreationMode.Private);
```

but it didn't work. I launch the app for the first time and put my credentials and check the checkbox. then I get out from the app and launch it again but nothing happens. the login page appears again. what did I do wrong? sorry for the long post.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From shared code , can not see that the second time launching app with the checked checkbox first time not dealing with the logic can go to main page directly.

About Login button click method here :

```
button.Click += delegate {
            //set the data to the loginpage
            //mOnLoginInforCompleted.inputLoginInforCompleted(MyeditText1.Text.ToString(), MyeditText2.Text.ToString());
            WSlogin.WebService2 ws = new WSlogin.WebService2();
            ws.LoginAsync(MyeditText1.Text, MyeditText2.Text);
            ws.LoginCompleted += Ws_LoginCompleted;                              
            };
```

Each time you will connect to server to login , the logic of checkbox seems not uesd here. I think the **solution** that you can check whether contain the stored user data before logining. Such as follow sample code:

```
if (UserInfo.Username != null && UserInfo.Password != null){

 //go to main page

}else{

    WSlogin.WebService2 ws = new WSlogin.WebService2();
    ws.LoginAsync(MyeditText1.Text, MyeditText2.Text);
    ws.LoginCompleted += Ws_LoginCompleted; 

}
```